# Python3 can't find urllib3

Tags: python-3.x, urllib3

I have Python 2.7.3 installed alongside Python 3.2.3 on an Ubuntu system.

I've installed urllib3 using pip and can import it from the python shell. When I open the python3 shell, I get a can't find module error when trying to import urllib3. help('modules') from within the shell also doesn't list urllib3.

Any ideas on how to get python3 to recognize urllib3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install it for each version of Python you have - if `pip` installs it for Python 2.7, it won't be accessible from 3.2.

There doesn't seem to be a `pip-3.2` script, but you can try `easy_install3 urllib3`.